# Unable to log in on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm unable to login with my Minecraft account. I keep on getting an invalid username/password error. I tried changing my username twice and so far it still hasn't worked.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried logging in with your email instead?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have migrated to a Mojang account, you will have had to login with your ***e-mail*** and password instead of your username.

This has been the case for a long while now.

Comment: He has to be using a migrated account, as you can't get to the change name button without having one.